# After termination, very next day you log in to your company email id and sent some documents to your personal id, what should happen?

Tags: professionalism

Company termintes you without giving any reasons, they had not paid last 3 months salaries. And you have logged to company email id, what should happened??
How you can get your salaries from them.
And there HR keeps telling you, you did this illegally. What you will do.

Comment: Ideally you should be forwarding any important personal documents to your personal email address as soon as you receive them. This should only really apply to work-related personal documents (like payslips) though - everything else should ideally go directly to your personal account.

Comment: What kind of documents where it? Was it sensible/restricted information or some personal file?

Comment: if you have not email forwarded IP / confidential / work related data from your company, you should be fine. It is their mistake that they did not change the credentials. Regarding the salaries, you have to report the issue to the authorities depending on your locale. In my country it is illegal not to pay somebody for a period he has already worked.

Comment: @GePeace Would you argue the same if someone who still has a key goes sneaking around the office? I don't think the cops will agree.

Comment: @Dukeling It does not work that way. Employee might have assumed that the company left him to enter the account to forward his personal email (in the company I work, many time I used to forward personal data to the company email). In some locales, company email might be considered personal as well if it is not signed through a contract.

Comment: You should be allowed time to gather personal belonging and that would include email.

Comment: What is the location, unlikely they would do this unles they thought they were safe... or management has all gone on the run, or the owner is locked up

Comment: As David answered, your actions sound fairly risky. To take it a step further, stolen work documents may not be admissible in an action if you pursue a legal cause. In the future, you should forward them or print them while still employed.

Answer (score 3):

1. If a company misses even 1 salary payment, it's time to move to a new company as soon as possible and talk to a lawyer immediately.
2. Yes, once you are terminated, you are no longer authorized to log in to their system. Get a lawyer. Also, keep any personal documentation you generate where you can get to it. All the emails and files on their systems are their property.
3. If they missed 3 salary payments, you have a case against them for nonpayment. Get a lawyer.

A company that cannot make payroll is essentially doomed, and if you are vindictive at all, make sure that all the companies with which they have business relationships know all about it, with documentation. (But don't expect those companies to hire you if you do this, or any other company that finds out you spilled the beans like that. Makes you a risk.)

Comment: "once you are terminated, you are no longer authorized to log in to their system". Says who? I have often worked out a notice period and continued to log in, send email on the company's behalf, make code changes, etc. Unless they send you home, I would expect you to keep working

Comment: @Mawg During a notice period you are not yet terminated, i.e. still under contract. With respect to this case, we lack details on which was the case.

Comment: It is not clear to me whether the OP was legally at work and performing company duties, or snuck in to the office to send email

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the United States, the [Computer Fraud and Abuse Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Fraud_and_Abuse_Act) prescribes penalties for unauthorized access that I wouldn't care to face.  It's been ruled that having working credentials is not necessarily authorized access, if you have good reason to believe your authorization is revoked (such as being fired).  Don't access company assets after being terminated, unless you have some other permission to do so.